# Applying a function to a nested loop

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, loops

```js
//Problem 3a:
for (var a=1; a<12; a++) {
    for (var b=00; b<60; b++) {
        for (var c=00; c<60; c++) {
            console.log(a + ':' + b + ':' + c + 'AM');
        }
    }
}
for (var alpha=12; alpha<13; alpha++) {
    for (var x=00; x<60; x++) {
        for (var y=00; y<60; y++) {
            console.log(alpha + ':' + x + ':' + y + 'PM');
        }
    }
}
for (var d=1; d<13; d++) {
    for (var e=00; e<60; e++) {
        for (var f=00; f<60; f++) {
            console.log(d + ':' + e + ':' + f + 'PM');
        }
    }
}

//Problem 3b:
function oneToTwo(number) {
    if (number < 10 && number >= 0) {
        return '0' + number;
    } else 
        return number;
    }

//Now apply to Problem 3a:
for (var q=0; q<10; q++) {
    oneToTwo(q);   
}
```

I am just beginning to learn Javascript and have written a for loop where the output should be the seconds in every minute in every hour in one day, on a 12-hour clock. The second part of the question was to write a function that turns any one digit number to its respective two digit number. I think I have written both of these correctly, but I am having trouble applying it to the for loop. can someone help me with this please???

[for loop and function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDZ4j.png)

Comment: Its better, if you post your code here rather than showing as a image.

Comment: Please paste your code here using the `code snippet button (<>)` just beside the image button when you ask your question.

Comment: thank you! does it show up better now? @dork

Comment: your code is going t o execute as fast as your processor allows.  Client side javascript uses setIntverval or setTimeout  in order to control actual timing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

> setInterval(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 1000);

1000 refers to 1000 ms which is 1 second

You can replace function(){} with your function name

```html
<script>setInterval(function(){ console.log(new Date().toLocaleTimeString());+"\n"; }, 1000);</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use your `oneToTwo` function in the loop:

```
for (var a = 1; a < 12; a++) {
  for (var b = 00; b < 60; b++) {
    for (var c = 00; c < 60; c++) {
      console.log(oneToTwo(a) + ':' + oneToTwo(b) + ':' + oneToTwo(c) + 'AM');
    }
  }
}
```